# CrawlerProcess - run from manager and get stats from Spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to create a manager for my spiders and record the stats from each crawl job to a sqlite db, unfortunately I can't manage to run the crawlers with CrawlerProcess from a separate python script. I've been looking for possible answers but there is nothing similar/recent out there.

```
import datetime
import os
from spiders import MySpider # example
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Float, DateTime, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

jobstore = {
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
}
# Set up a thread pool executor
executor = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
}
# Create the scheduler object with the jobstore and executor
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(jobstores=jobstore, executors=executor)
# Create the SQLAlchemy engine and session factory
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///stats.sqlite')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# Define the database model for the spider stats
Base = declarative_base()
class SpiderStats(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'spider_stats'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    spider_name = Column(String)
    request_count = Column(Integer)
    response_count = Column(Integer)
    item_count = Column(Integer)
    elapsed_time_seconds = Column(Float)
    start_time = Column(DateTime)

# Check if the table already exists
inspector = inspect(engine)
if not inspector.has_table('spider_stats'):
    # Create the table if it doesn't exist
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def extract_spider_stats(spider):
    # Extract the spider stats
    stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()

    # Create a new database record with the stats data
    session = Session()
    spider_stats = SpiderStats(
        spider_name=spider.name,
        request_count=stats.get('downloader/request_count', 0),
        response_count=stats.get('downloader/response_count', 0),
        item_count=stats.get('item_scraped_count', 0),
        elapsed_time_seconds=stats.get('elapsed_time_seconds', 0),
        start_time=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    session.add(spider_stats)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
    # Print the spider stats to the console
    print('SPIDER STATS: ', stats)

def run_scrapy_spider(spider_name):
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    crawler = process.create_crawler(spider_name)
    process.crawl(crawler)
    process.start()
    process.join()
    stats_obj = crawler.stats
    stats_dict = stats_obj.get_stats()
    print (stats_dict)

scheduler.add_job(run_scrapy_spider, 'interval', seconds=30, args=[MySpider])

scheduler.start()
```

I'm currently not trying to integrate the db yet because I can't get the crawler to run with CrawlerProcess. I would just like the job to run and print the stats to start with.  `crawl_manager.py` is located in the scrapy folder the structure is:

```
scrapy/ <- directory I'm trying to run jobs from.
    scrapy/ 
        spiders/
            myspider.py
            ...
        ...
    crawl_manager.py
    ...
```

from the current directory I can run `scrapy crawl myspider` (class MySpider, name="myspider") and it runs without issues.

When trying to run the manager:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

I don't have anything other than the spider running concurrently and would prefer to use CrawlerProcess than CrawlerRunner.

Tried `process.start(install_signal_handlers=False)`

```
2023-03-22 15:35:27 [apscheduler.executors.default] ERROR: Job "run_scrapy_spider (trigger: interval[0:00:30], next run at: 2023-03-22 15:35:57 CST)" raised an exception

    process.start(install_signal_handlers=False)    # <-  just add this parameter.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/x/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 383, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/x/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/asyncioreactor.py", line 254, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/x/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1299, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(cast(ReactorBase, self))
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/x/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 843, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that since APScheduler runs the jobs as subprocesses the jobs don't run in the main thread from the manager and this creates a problem with the CrawlerProcess.

A working solution is to use a PIPE in a simple run subprocess and then parsing the output to get the stats. I've tested this with multiple spiders and works without issues.

```
def run_scrapy_spider(spider_name):
    print (f'Job started for {spider_name} at {datetime.now()}')
    p = run(['scrapy', 'crawl', spider_name], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output = str(p)
    ...
```

output is then a string where I regexed the json object with the crawler stats then used json.loads() to make a python dictionary before sending it to fill the sqlite db.